# /etc/sudoers is owned by gid 33, should be 0, and when I try pkexec I get "authentication failed"

Tags: permissions, apache2, sudo, chmod, visudo

I was trying to get access and write permissions to my apache sites-available folder over ssh/sftp. I didn't really understand what I was doing to be honest and ran the following commands:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data USERNAME
$ sudo chgrp -R www-data
$ sudo chmod -R g+w /etc/
```

After running these commands I can no longer connect via filezilla. When I attempt to use sudo I get the following:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by gid 33, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I did some digging and found that I should run `pkexec visudo`, but when I run that and enter my password I get `==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===`.

I'm at a loss and am not sure how to fix this. Obviously I broke something changing the permissions of /etc/.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the password for the root user, try logging in as root (in a tty by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>), then execute this:

```
chown root:root /etc/sudoers
```

Otherwise, you need to have physical access to the server to boot a live USB system to execute the above command as root from the live session.

Comment: How should the user do that if he cannot use sudo?  Please [edit] your answer to add that relevant info and then ping me @fabby so I can turn my downvote into an upvote.

Comment: I edited my answer @Fabby

Comment: Edited and upvoted: Now it's a good answer!  **;-)**