# Locked Root : Advantage/Disadvantage from security point of view?

Tags: password, security, root

I want to know the advantage and disadvantage of having locked root account from security stand point.

Why not set a password and allow root access as some other distributions do?

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone would ever consider no password for root access to be beneficial unless you're using a test system and don't want to repeatedly put the password in. As you say it's a security issue, so unless you're happy to give anyone using your computer access to all your files then I'd avoid it. There is a way to set no password for specific commands if you happy for certain programs to run with root access which is the best way to go about it I'd say. Unless it's a test system or something you're happy to potentially loose the files on then I'd keep sudo protected with a password.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Advantages_and_Disadvantages

Comment: @user68186 I want to mean the default settings of ubuntu. Is it locked root or no password?

Comment: If I remember rightly it's something to do with the sudoers file (if you want to allow specific commands to run with sudo but no password)but I can't remember off the top of my head I'll have to go and look it up. I've not done anything with it for a while.

Comment: @rohtua then why ubuntu follow this? For user experience only?

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. Ubuntu defaults to asking you for a password when using sudo? I'd hope it does that's the best way to do it unless you want allow unrestricted access to anyone using your machine. EDIT: sorry misread it then. I get what you mean now. The link above seems to the reasons.

Comment: I would say the second part of the question "Why distributions like Fedora and others do not consider this?" is off-topic, as the answers to that will [primarily be opinion based](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 3):

> As the title says, I want to know the advantage and disadvantage of having no password for root account from security stand point.

Ubuntu locks the root account by default, so you can't log in as root.

But you can become root by different means.

This reduces the attack surface significantly. It ensures that people don't make a habit of logging in as root, to avoid hassle - which is a security risk. It means that only tasks that *require* root privileges will normally be started with root privileges, because the user has to invoke some mechanism to elevate the process to root, e.g. use `sudo ...`.

The downside is, of course, that root account is not accessible, and if you [screw up the alternate mechanisms such as sudo, you may have a problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138478/etc-sudoers-is-owned-by-gid-33-should-be-0-and-when-i-try-pkexec-i-get-authe).

This problem is in Ubuntu's view smaller than the security gain. If a user disagrees, they may freely enable the root account, by setting a password.

As to why other distributions do it in different ways - habits die hard. Many are used to having a root user around. Others may not want to rely on a `sudo` setup (Debian doesn't even install sudo in the minimal install), or they perceive the users should configure authentication.

The trend is also what's behind UAC in Windows. Provide limited permissions by default, but allow a user to elevate a process *if* required. The philosophy is the same.